# Image Processing a Metal Dot Peen Data Matrix / QR Code

Tags: barcode-scanner, qr-code

I have a series of metal data matrix codes I'm trying to read, and my scanner has a hell of a time with them.

Here's an example of one:[image: Example Data Matrix Code]

I'm interested if there's a way to process this image into black and white image that a scanner can read easily.  I've been trying different combinations of filters or editing levels in GIMP, but nothing comes out looking clear enough for a barcode scanner.

It would be great if there was possibly a python library to do this but I must not be searching for the right thing.

Comment: tempted to suggest scanning a rubbing of them - but that's not fun

Comment: Funny enough I didn't think of that.  Goes to show I'm probably over-engineering this

Comment: Why are you trying to decode a cheese grater?

Comment: Welcome to my job 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lighting is important, and imaging might work better on the side with depressions, because on the other side, raised bumps cast shadows. Try lighting from two sides, or using ring-lighting around the lens.

You might also ink the bumps with a ink-pad, used for rubber stamps, and press on paper to make a print to use for OCR.

After you have taken the best image, adjust contrast, brightness and gamma (or the whole monochrome light curve) with a tool such as the free [IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/), which runs in native Windows OS or in Linux under wine. The 8bf filter [SmartCurve](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Graphic/Graphic-Plugins/SmartCurve.shtml) can be added to IrfanView to enable fine adjustments. There are many [similar free and commercial image processing tools](https://alternativeto.net/software/irfanview/).

Once you've established optimal settings for OCR results, you can automate batch processing of the images.